# VideoCapture(0) and VideoCapture.open(0) Do Not Seem To Work With CMake (UBUNTU) (OpenCV4)

Tags: c++11, ubuntu, cmake, g++

I am trying to open my in-built camera in order to make a Face Detection program, but I notice that VideoCapture.open(0) does not work when I attempt to run through a cmake compilation, but DOES work when I compile and run through g++.

This program is part of a project, and compiling through CMake is necessary, but nothing seems to work...

(I'm using Ubuntu)

My code compiles and runs, opening the in-built camera (returning "true" on `if(capture.isOpened())`), when I use

```
g++ main.cpp FaceDetection.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

but returns false on `if(capture.isOpened())` and does not open the in-built camera when I compile through cmake.

Any ideas on what I should do for this to run like it runs when I compile it with g++?

**Edit**: Removed my code, as it wasn't a problem with the code at all. Will answer my own question as I found a solution.

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` will show you **exact command lines** used for compile and link the project's executable. You may compare these command line with ones you use manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran `make VERBOSE=1`, `cmake ../ --log-level=VERBOSE`, and

```
g++ main.cpp FaceDetection.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

as Tsyvarev suggested, and found that g++ was including opencv from /usr/include while cmake was including opencv from /usr/local

I found this **SOLUTION**:
Ran `cd /opt/opencv/build && make uninstall` first and then ran `make` in my project folder, which actually solved the problem and opened the camera.

I'm not sure what caused this, but if this happens to anyone, hope this helps!